# Find value subject to several constraints

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I want to find the value of $x'$ such that all of the following constraints are satisfied:

$x' * o' < x * o$

$ o' < o $

$ x \le x'$

These are all variables but I always know the values of $x$, $o$ and $o'$. I'm sure that this is easy to solve but I have been completely unable to!

Cheers,

Pete

EDIT:

For clarification, what I'm actually trying to do is place two bets on a betting exchange such that I make a profit regardless of the outcome of an event.

I place a back bet of £x at odds of $back_odds$, if that wins then my payout is $£x*back_odds$, I have to place a lay bet at lower odds but with a higher stake in order to make a profit on all outcomes.

Comment: It depends on if the values $x$, $o$ and $o'$ are positive or negative. Further try to use symbol other than $o$ since it looks like $0$.

Comment: Are $x'$ and $x$ related in some way, and $o$ and $o'$, too?  If so, please describe.  If not, please use four different characters (and not $o$).  What range of variables are allowable?  Is it $\mathbb{R}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that $x$, $o$, and $o'$ are all positive; you should be able to work out solutions in other cases by a similar method.

In this case, we need $x \le x' < x(o/o')$ as our sole requirement, which can be determined by dividing the first expression by $o'$.

Keep in mind for the other cases that when multiplying/dividing by negative numbers, inequalities are reversed.